# Powershell creating shortcut

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that won't update the $TargetFile Properly. Here is my code:

```
$TargetFile = "C:\Users\wjschan\AppData\Roaming\DAS Toolbox\DAS Toolbox.exe"

$ShortcutFile = "$StartMenuPath\$ApplicationName.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$NewTarget = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.IconLocation = $IconLocation
$Shortcut.Save()
```

But when I right click on the shortcut it lists "This PC" as the target. However if I put this code in, it works fine:

```
$ShortcutFile = "$StartMenuPath\$ApplicationName.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$NewTarget = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Users\wjschan\AppData\Roaming\DAS Toolbox\DAS Toolbox.exe"
$Shortcut.IconLocation = $IconLocation
$Shortcut.Save()
```

I'm at a loss as to why hard coding the file path works but a variable does not. It's worked before if $TargetFile points to a differnt path (Say a network share).

Win10, Build 1607 (Current Business Branch) - and no I can't get a newer build.

Comment: Can't reproduce it.

Comment: Powershell ISE?

Comment: Powershell ISE, yes.

Comment: Ugh...try it in an actual session rather than the ISE.

Comment: Irreproducible issues in ISE? Never seen that one before :). Basically it's common practice to copy and paste your application into a completely NEW session (not a new tab in ISE) otherwise you have no idea how previous attempts can affect your script.

Comment: Meh, in my opinion better is to edit your code in the ISE if that is what you want to do but never run it there. Run it in a regular powershell session.

Comment: Make sure `$TargetFile` is a string, if you not sure, try `"$TargetFile"` or `$TargetFile.ToString()`

Comment: @iRon Wrapping it in quotes did the trick. I didn't realize that trick. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart you are incorrect. I was doing what I posted. The first section I had $TargetFile = "C:\Users\wjschan\AppData\Roaming\DAS Toolbox\DAS Toolbox.exe". That is how it was defined. The second piece it was not needed.

Comment: Your code is missing pieces (e.g., it does not show the definition of `$StartMenuPath` and `$ApplicationName`). Update your question to show a minimal example of the _actual_ code that doesn't work, and I can remove the downvote.

Comment: Your comment as to why it was down voted was incorrect. If you are gonig to downvote someone, at least put in the correct comment. Especially if you are downvoting me for not putting everythign in. ironic that you would do that. I accept the new reason, but it's a solved question. Why are you even bothering with this.

Comment: It is for your benefit to help you improve your question(s)--feel free to update it. My comment was intended to mean, "post the _actual_ code you are running that isn't working," not merely a subset of it. Fortunately in your case someone was able to guess the cause. In the future, I recommend following the [SSCCE principle](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently your `$TargetFile` is not a `String` type.
I suspect it is of a `IO.FileInfo` type as you probably dynamically building up the path.
To find out what object type it actually concerns, try: `$TargetFile.PSTypeNames`

To force it to a `String`, wrap it into quotes, like:

```
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "$TargetFile"
```

Or use: `$TargetFile.ToString()` or `[String]$TargetFile`